# Exclude part_no

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to select PART_NO from this table (INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST_TAB) but not if the part has a TRANSACTION_CODE  of NREC or NISS. I.e PART_NO 101247 should not be returned but 1001709 should be returned.

[image: 1012427]

[image: 10001709]

If I enter

```
SELECT  
PART_NO
FROM INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST_TAB WHERE TRANSACTION_CODE !='NISS' or TRANSACTION_CODE != 'NREC';
```

it still returns part number 1012427 because it obviously has other transaction codes that are not 'NISS' or 'NREC'.

Comment: Try `AND` instead of `OR`.

Comment: That returns no rows.

Comment: Ah yes, I misunderstood your aim, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a not in the code with NISS and NREC

```
  SELECT
  PART_NO 
  FROM INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST_TAB
  WHERE PART_NO NOT IN (
    SELECT
    PART_NO 
    FROM INVENTORY_TRANSACTION_HIST_TAB
    WHERE TRANSACTION_CODE IN ('NISS','NREC')
  )
```

Comment: This works, thank you scais (and others for their suggestions).

Answer (score 2):

This is where analytic functions come to the rescue:

```
SELECT part_no,
       <other columns>
FROM   (SELECT part_no,
               <other columns>,
               max(CASE WHEN transaction_code IN ('NISS', 'NREC') THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) OVER (PARTITION BY part_no) invalid_code_present
        FROM   inventory_transaction_hist_tab)
WHERE  invalid_code_present = 0;
```

The subquery finds the max value of 1 across each part_no if any of the rows for that part_no have a transaction_code of NISS or NREC. This value is returned for all rows.

The outer query then filters the results to only include part_no rows that don't have any rows with the excluded transaction_codes.

N.B. I've assumed that you want more information from the rows than just the part_no. If that's not the case, then an aggregate query should do the trick:

```
SELECT part_no
FROM   inventory_transaction_hist_tab
GROUP BY part_no
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN transaction_code IN ('NISS', 'NREC') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you *only* want the part number, and only distinct values - so you only see one result for 1001709 rather than 6, then you could use conditional aggregation:

```
select part_no
from inventory_transaction_hist_tab
group by part_no
having max(case when transaction_code in ('NISS', 'NREC') then transaction_code end) is null;
```

If you want to see all rows for 1001709 then an alternative to @scaisEdge's query is to use `not exists`:

```
select part_no, transaction_code
from inventory_transaction_hist_tab t1
where not exists (
  select *
  from inventory_transaction_hist_tab t2
  where t2.part_no = t1.part_no
  and t2.transaction_code in ('NISS', 'NREC')
);
```

You can try both and see which performs better. Or @Boneist's, which has the advantage of only hitting the table once, which is likely to offset any overhead from the analytic function.